# AWS working for IIS, but not for NodeJS on the same port

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS EC2 instance on Windows Server 2008 R2, I deployed an application in IIS on port 80. I am able to access it anywhere.  The security group is as follows:
HTTP  TCP  80  0.0.0.0/0

Then, I installed NodeJS for windows and deployed a simple node application to the same port. When I browse to localhost on the server I see my application working, but when i browse from a different pc, I cannot access it. How is it accessible from IIS but not from NodeJS?

I've seen this question on stackoverflow and the answer is ussually to set the TCP port in security groups in AWS cosole but I've already done that and it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: is the nodejs running on the same port? if it not, did u allow that port for public access?

Comment: yes i stopped IIS, and put nodejs on the same port 80. I can browse to it locally but not publicly

Comment: try pinging to your server from a different computer. If you get timeout then there is a issue with ports, if not there is something wrong with ur nodejs server setup (u didn't post ur code so i can't debug it). Also look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/271824/node-js-is-not-accessible-from-external-ips-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was the port. It turns out that the AWS Windows server 2008 AMI opens the port only for a limited set of IIS services only. I had to set another rule to open the same port for NodeJS.

Comment: what rule did you set to open the port for node js? I tried a rule in the firewall of EC2 that sets all ports to open and any protocol and still its working locally and not from another PC. (trying to use node server without IIS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are having the same issue, if you install nodejs you will need to change some windows firewall settings to expose the port:

1. Open Start Menu -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
2. Click "Inbound Rules" from the left window
3. Click "New Rule..." in the Actions window on the right side
4. follow the prompts to customize the rule and be sure to add the port that your nodejs application is using. Make sure to name the rule so that you recognize it later
5. In the Inbound Rules window find and double click the rule you just created. Under Programs and Services, select "This Program:" and browse to your node.exe file.
6. Last but not least make sure this port is open in AWS console security group inbound rules too.